# How can I link data to TStringGrid?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How can i link the data of my table in database with TStringGrid?

Comment: You can't. Use a DBGrid instead.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, you can. Manually :)

Comment: Haha, yes, I was going to edit that in, but you beat me to it :P

Comment: @TLama could u please let me know what that code .. and hw can I write it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** *As stated by Llama, it is not binding, the below code merely shows the query values on the stringlist.*
Please test it because I'm not near Delphi atm:

```
var
  fCol, fLine : integer;
begin
  for fCol := 0 to Query1.Fields.Count-1 do
  begin
    stringgrid1.Cells[fCol, 0] := Query1.Fields[fCol].DisplayLabel;
    StringGrid1.ColWidths[fCol] := Query1.Fields[fCol].DisplayWidth;
  end;
  fLine := 1;
  with Query1 do
  begin
    while not eof do
    begin
      for fCol := 0 to Fields.Count-1 do
      begin
        stringgrid1.cells[fCol, fLine] := Fields.Fields[fCol].asstring;
      end;
      inc(fLine);
      next;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with "binding". It only prints out a dataset to the string grid at a certain time.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't. Yet, part of the solution in this case was figuring out what the asker really needed, and aamof, he didn't need a "binding" after all, just a way to print the query on a StringList. After all he said he was still learning and one of the first exercises on Delphi classes (at least around here) have something to do with my solution, hence the answer.